# Label text not updating straight away after download c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am in the process of creating a simple application that downloads a zip file to a given directory this works fine and I have manage to show the download progress and update a progress bar. The problem that I am having is once the download has been completed the application extracts the zip file to the given destination this all works fine. My problem is that my label is not changing it's text straight away it seems to wait till after the extraction has been completed.

What should happen is this: label text says "Downloading File" once download is complete it should say "Extracting File"

I think the issue is with the Async download method but I can't be certain.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace CloudBarsInstaller
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(@"C:\NEWBARS\NewInstaller\BarsStaging\Distributable.zip"), @"C:\Temp2\Distributable.zip");
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            lblStatus.Content = "Extracting Bars Zip File";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            //once download is done extract the file

            var directoryPath = @"C:\Temp2\Distributable.zip";
           string extractPath = @"C:\Temp2\BarsInstaller";

            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(directoryPath))
            {
                //zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;

                zip.ExtractProgress += zipProgress;
                zip.ExtractAll(extractPath,ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);

            }
            //ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(directoryPath, extractPath);
        }
        private void zipProgress(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_EntryBytesWritten)
                this.progressBar.Value = (int)((e.BytesTransferred * 100) / e.TotalBytesToTransfer);

            else if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_AfterExtractAll)
                this.progressBar.Value = 100;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: The place where you update the label with the text "Downloading File" seems to be missing from the code you posted

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved this, the issue is because of thread locking.  I changed the code to download the file on button click (which is easier) and to update the label I used this code:

```
lblStatus.Invoke((Action)delegate
{

    lblStatus.Text = "Extracting Bars Zip File";

});
```